# Javascript remove elements by class name

Tags: javascript, dom

How we can remove the all div by same name of class.

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]">
```

Comment: Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")).forEach(el=>el.remove())

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input.form-control")).forEach(function(n) {n.parentNode.removeChild(n);});` - magic.

Comment: @Jonasw No `.remove()` in IE.

Comment: @melpomene Or arrow functions. Or `Array.from`. Or `Array#forEach`. Why do we still care about archaic browsers? IE isn't even in development any more.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol `Array#forEach` is supported since IE 9. We care because people use it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiY1Y7jt_nUAhUEkpQKHQHiAw4QFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw) And [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) use to iterate the element

```
document.querySelectorAll('.classname').forEach(function(a){
a.remove()
})
```

**Example snippet**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(function(a) {
  a.remove()
})
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]">
<input class="form" type="text" name="option[]" value="not same class">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]">
```

Comment: Actually, it's not `Array#forEach` but [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Answer (score 1):

My approach might be this

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.test');  
for (var element of elements) {
   element.remove();
   // or 
   // element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$(".form-control").remove();
```

Without jQuery:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
elems.forEach(function(element) {
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
});
```

Comment: `NodeList`s do not have a `forEach` method.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol They do now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: @melpomene Preposterous. Next you'll be telling me that JavaScript is a server-side language now :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) feature of JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class-name").forEach(el => el.remove())
```